# premature end of file /boot/vmlinuz... error while booting dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

I have a dual boot computer with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I've had no big problems until today, when I tried to boot Ubuntu. I see this on my screen:

```
error: premature end of file /boot/vmlinuz-4.2-35-generic
error: you need to load the kernel first
unaligned pointer 0x660a660a
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

[image]

Comment: What picture? Maybe you should post a link?

Answer (score 3):

> error: premature end of file `/boot/vmzlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic`.

That means that somehow the file containing the kernel was truncated somewhere in the middle. You'll need to reinstall the kernel package but you'll need to boot a different kernel for that since this one is broken.

I'll assume that you have a different kernel (older?) installed for Ubuntu.

1. When you boot your computer [open the Grub menu](/q/16042/175814) and select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" entry. In the appearing submenu select any entry that doesn't refer to kernel "4.2.0-25" and that isn't tagged with "recovery mode". The names may be localized to your language; just choose the corresponding translated entries.
2. Log in normally and open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T). Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -f linux-generic
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.2.0-51-generic
   ```

   Reboot and everything should be back to normal.

   If you run into issues during with the `apt-get` commands please edit your question, select, copy and paste their output into your question and notify me in the comment section of this answer.

If you don't have a different kernel to boot, you'll have to use a Live DVD/USB which makes things somewhat more complicated. If that's the case, please leave a comment and I'll extend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanku for your answer. Can I reinstall linux kernal by a live usb (by chroot command). Because I haven't any older kernal as you said in your answer.

Comment: I have no internet connection also.

Comment: Ugh, no internet connection will make this *much* more complicated bordering on impossible. It's difficult to foresee which packages you'll need to (re-)install. I sincerely suggest that you try to get an internet connection running on the Live DVD/USB that you're going to use to restore the broken kernel. Otherwise it's probably easier to reinstall everything (while retaining `/home` so you won't lose your data – back it up anyway just to be safe though).